# ¿Crear consulta con LIKE parametrizado? (JAVA/UcanAccess)

Tags: java, sql, ms-access-2010

Buenas! vengo aqui con una pequeña pregunta: ¿Como exactamente se podria escribir una consulta usando un Like y que sea parametrizada? estoy usando [UcanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) con JAVA.

Tengo una ventana en mi programa que requiere el uso del Like. Intente primero escribiendolo "normal" de esta forma, pero no era lo que yo buscaba:

```
SELECT Diagnostico FROM Historial WHERE CedulaP LIKE ? ORDER BY Fecha ASC
```

Necesitaba insertarle el caracter de porcentaje (%) para que funcionara como yo buscaba.. asi que lo que hice yo es escribir lo siguiente:

```
SELECT Diagnostico FROM Historial WHERE CedulaP LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') ORDER BY Fecha ASC
```

La consulta funciona bien, pero no se porque me entraron las dudas de que si hacerlo de esta manera es seguro, o no (por el tema de la [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)). Este codigo que escribi es donde yo preparo el `PreparedStatement` para ejecutar la consulta:

```
public ResultSet SelectQuery(String[] values, String query) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs;
    for(int i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
        stmt.setString(i + 1, values[i]);
    }
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    return rs;
}
```

Es segura la consulta de la forma como lo escribi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es segura, ya que no se puede hacer una subconsulta dentro de una cadena (que es lo que hiciste) por que se escaparía toda la sentencia, no tengas pendiente de la injección SQL problema sería si hicieras lo siguiente.

```
String variable ="(DELETE FROM Historial)as Hecho";
String query = "SELECT Diagnostico FROM Historial WHERE CedulaP LIKE CONCAT('%',"+varible+",'%') ORDER BY Fecha ASC";
```

Con el preparedStatement como lo tienes tu simplemente al concatenar pasaría así

```
String query = "SELECT Diagnostico FROM Historial WHERE CedulaP LIKE CONCAT('%','(DELETE FROM Historial)as Hecho','%') ORDER BY Fecha ASC";
```

Algo así.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder y esa explicacion sobre lo que ocurre al usar concat es muy utill... mil gracias..